# Error while trying to stream data from Kafka and store it in apache hudi

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

I am trying to store Kafka data in apache hudi

Spark version I am using is 3.3.1 Kafka clients 2.8.1 , hudi spark-sql-kafka 0-10-2.12
and I am getting error while writing that code
`org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool` error.

I am using the code.

https://github.com/soumilshah1995/hudi-kafka-learn/blob/main/lab1/hudi-kafka.py

Do we need to add or remove any library?

I included common pool jars 2.6.1 ,2.8.1 in jars in spark session still same issue

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error